# Can't run Flutter app error "FAILURE: Build failed with an exception."

Tags: android-studio, flutter, testing, dart, flutter-dependencies

This app is from Github
"https://github.com/wiltonribeiro/grocery_shop_flutter"

I was wondering if someone else is able to run it because i get some execution errors and I cant fix them.
I would appreciate it if someone can fix the issue
Cheers!

Edit: I appreciate your responses
**the error looks like this:**

"
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Android resource linking failed
> Output:  O:\grocery_shop_flutterbait\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:86: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
> O:\grocery_shop_flutterbait\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:87: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
> error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\arsla.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\6eab767dc8c1fd40d868c7361b7d30e9\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I
C:\Users\arsla\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar
--manifest
O:\grocery_shop_flutterbait\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml
-o
O:\grocery_shop_flutterbait\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_
-R
@O:\grocery_shop_flutterbait\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt
--auto-add-overlay
--java
O:\grocery_shop_flutterbait\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r
--custom-package
com.example.groceryshopflutter
-0
apk
--output-text-symbols
O:\grocery_shop_flutterbait\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt
--no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
Output:  C:\Users\arsla.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.1.0.aar\18619ad8df18189ffa8d36e63947ac33\res\values\values.xml:174:5-210:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

C:\Users\arsla.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.1.0.aar\18619ad8df18189ffa8d36e63947ac33\res\values\values.xml:174:5-210:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

error: failed linking references.
Command: C:\Users\arsla.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\6eab767dc8c1fd40d868c7361b7d30e9\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I
C:\Users\arsla\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar
--manifest
O:\grocery_shop_flutterbait\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml
-o
O:\grocery_shop_flutterbait\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_
-R
@O:\grocery_shop_flutterbait\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt
--auto-add-overlay
--java
O:\grocery_shop_flutterbait\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r
--custom-package
com.example.groceryshopflutter
-0
apk
--output-text-symbols
O:\grocery_shop_flutterbait\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt
--no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
""

Comment: please, provide error message

Comment: Sorry ,I just added it the post

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile it to android and i could fix this error by changing compileSdkVersion to 28

However the solution is applicable if you follow the instruction on https://github.com/wiltonribeiro/grocery_shop_flutter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works perfectly fine in the latest version.[product picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DIVA.png) (only for ios phone running).

*No need to worry>>> Only on terminal, It still tells an error message "Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
embedding. It's being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2. Follow the
steps at
[https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration"](https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration%22)*

[The output looks like this!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVaJI.png)

Comment: i am  confused becasue i am getting this error in android studio

""
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  O:\grocery_shop_flutterbait\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:86: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  ..(it continues...)

""

Comment: I am running this on android studio

Comment: I ran it on Android Studio too.. It worked for ios phone version, maybe not the android version.

Comment: is there a way we can fix that?
p.s I added the error to the post